# "Similar Questions" search should take the tags into account

Tags: feature-request, questions, similar-questions

Whenever I try and submit a question, I keep getting invalid results for "Questions that may already have your answer". From what I've seen, the suggested questions do not consider the tags that I've added to the question.

I really am not happy with getting C# suggestions when my question is about Eclipse RCP development!

Does Stack Overflow already do this? If so, perhaps the tags need to be weighted more highly. If not, they should—tags set the context of the question.

Comment: It's worth noting that, while you are not using C#, lessons can sometimes be drawn from answers if the substance is similar despite a different environment.

Comment: Side note: "suggested questions" somehow is less accurate than "Related" (which generally finds good matches and definitely uses tags). It may be easier to create question and look at "Related" (especially if you are not on the edge of "blocked due to too many deleted questions").

Answer (score 1):

From a tiny bit of research it appears that the tags themselves do not contribute very much to determining similar questions in the course of writing a new question.  There are two pieces of evidence that I argue support my hypothesis.

(1) Prediction of tags based on question content alone has been done before and doesn't seem like an incredibly hard problem, since the set of tags are generally closed.  See this paper: http://iccm-conference.org/2013-proceedings/papers/0077/paper0077.pdf

(2) Stackoverflow already provides some tag prediction when writing a question, and additionally similar questions are already brought up before even assigning tags to a new question that is being drafted.

Of course this is just speculation with a little bit of research.  Hopefully someone has the exact details on this.