# Update suggested questions when tags are added

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Should I not expect the suggested question list to be updated when I add tags?

Aren't the tags to help in questioning as well?

Comment: Related: [*“Similar Questions” search should take the tags into account*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269706/2751851)

Comment: I should have gotten this related question somewhere in the suggestions list. Well, thanks for doing manually.