# "Similar Questions" suggestor is not contextual

Tags: feature-request

When creating a new Question, the "Similar Questions" pane is not at all useful and I think it is a main contributor to why there are so many duplicate questions coming into SO.

**An Example:**

Went to create a typescript question this morning. For anyone that has worked with ts, technology context is key as it heavily augments the implementations. I tagged the question with `typescript` and `webpack`. The returned suggestions all sounded relevant to my question topic, but here these were the *"main"* tags on the first 3 questions: `cmake`, `python`, `android`.

**2 Main Suggestions:**

1. Show tags in against the question so I don't have to open them to see if they are relevant.
2. Update the query logic to include tags.

---

**Update:**
This questions was flagged to already have an answer in this question: ["Similar Questions" search should take the tags into account](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269706/similar-questions-search-should-take-the-tags-into-account). There is no answer in this question, and to quote the answer from ~6yrs ago

> "this is just speculation with a little bit of research. Hopefully someone has the exact details on this."

Comment: That the feature request has not been answered does not make this not a duplicate. Feature requests often aren't answered until the feature has been implemented. Obviously, this one hasn't. If you want to bring more attention to the feature request and argue for its implementation, you can post an answer there.