# Could we add tag names to the list of suggestions when writing a question?

Tags: feature-request, tags

When writing a question, there is a list of possibly related questions above the main question body and below the title. It can be helpful when asking language-specific questions, but when it gets more generalized, there's a problem.

Take this simple question example: "How do I print colored output to the terminal in Rust?" When writing that as a question, I get at *least* 10-15 results with nearly identical titles. Great, someone's already asked my question and I'll get answers! But when I go to the similar questions, they're "How do I print colored output to the terminal" but in C++, Python, Bash, etc. I also notice that the tab's title in the browser *does* have the question's tag name when I go to it.

For example, go to this question: [How to print colored text to the terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/q/287871/16775594). The tab's title is `python - How to print col...` even though `python -`  isn't in the actual question's title.

So my request: could we add tag names to the list of suggested related questions so that we can tell which language the question is about without actually having to go to the question and look at the tags?

Comment: I haven't evaluated this to determine to what extent this already exists, but it would be especially useful if that list were _filtered_ or, at least, _prioritized_ based on tag overlap. (I imagine the latter would be easier and less likely to result in false negatives based on subjective decisions in which tags to include.)

Comment: Related from main meta: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170056/please-show-tags-in-the-list-of-suggested-questions-that-may-already-have-your-a, https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2031/please-show-the-tags-associated-with-each-question-listed-in-the-related-questi, https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177947/refresh-questions-that-may-already-have-your-answer-after-adding-tags-based-on?noredirect=1&lq=1, https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/204508/make-suggested-questions-that-might-have-my-answer-aware-of-the-tags

Comment: And here on M.SO https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269706/similar-questions-search-should-take-the-tags-into-account

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just one of those no-brainers to me. Heck yes, we need this.

But specifically this - adding the (language) tag name to the title. Don't filter because software filters will always be flawed and will contextually filter too much. We like to reason from the perspective of the old reliables such as C++ and Java, but that tends to make us fall flat for the younger generation tags such as [R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r), [JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) or [Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python).

No, just provide enough information, so the brain filter can do its thing. Clean, simple, and doable.